# Automated Decision Making Using Decision Tree Classifier

Tags: python, decision-tree

I'm trying to code a decision making process which otherwise require extensive IF ELSE scripting, and I'm wondering if it's possible to express the whole process in a form of root, decision and leave nodes in scikit learn's decision tree classifier.

Note that there is no training involved, just a direct user-definition of the nodes.

Comment: Why do you need `sklearn decision tree classifier` for that? By default a nested IF ELSE is a "decision" tree. What's the point of a classifier since you are not training it? You are still going to define every decision explicitly.

Comment: IIUC what you need is a tree data structure where you store each node with a condition instead of a value. Just make a custom `class` for this and store your conditions in `lambda` functions.

Comment: To use a traditional ML model like a decision tree, you need data to train the model on period. (If you don't have or want data then look for some other approach)

Comment: Manually defining the classifier serves the purpose of a control experiment. This would keep the model structure consistent when I compare this Manual Model against a Data-Driven Model trained from actual transaction histories. Purpose is to showcase the difference in automating decision principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the intent, but a decision tree is a very particular algorithm with goals much different than yours. Depending on the kind of conditions and how many of them you have, you should first evaluate if a map (dictionary) is more appropiate. If you still think you need to go ahead with a tree structure, you should implement your own tree as @akshay-sehgal said.

You can use this simple `Node` class that stores the condition as a lambda, in the attribute `left_condition`. If `left_condition` is None, the node is a leaf and returns `value`. Otherwise it's a decision node and goes either to the `left` or `right` node, as you can see in the `get_value` function:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(left_condition = None, value = None, left = None, right= None):
    self.left_condition = left_condition
    self.value = value
    self.left = left
    self.right = right


def get_value(tree,data):
    node = tree
    while node.left_condition is not None:
        if left_condition(data):
            node = node.left
        else:
            node = node.right
    return node.value
```